# keystonejs with mongoosastic error _doc.execPopulate()

Tags: node.js, keystonejs, mongoosastic

I am attempting to plugin mongoosastic into my Keystone JS application and populate a relationship field. Cannot find documentation and since keystone wraps the schema model, mongoose documentation needs to be somewhat translated. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;
var mongoose = (keystone.mongoose);
var deepPopulate = require('mongoose-deep-populate')(mongoose);
var mongoosastic = require('mongoosastic');
var ProductCategory = keystone.List('ProductCategory').schema;

var Product = new keystone.List('Product', {
    map: { name: 'title' },
    autokey: { path: 'slug', from: 'title', unique: true },
    track: true,
});

Product.add(
    'Optional', {
        volume: { type: String },
        price: { type: Types.Number },
    },
    'Taxonomy', {
        category: {
            type: Types.Relationship,
            ref: 'ProductCategory',
            index: true,
            many: true,
            es_schema:ProductCategory,
            es_indexed: true,
            es_type: 'nested',
            es_include_in_parent: true
        },
    }

);


Product.schema.plugin(deepPopulate);
Product.schema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
   hosts: [
         'host here'
    ] 
    populate: [
        {path: 'category'}
    ]
})
Product.defaultColumns = 'title, brand, category, state|20%';
Product.register();
```

[this is the error I am receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9uKS.jpg)

Comment: were you able to get elastic search to index your ProductCategory ID?

Comment: @Whnunlife Yes but not using Mongoosastic but rather the Elastic Search NodeJS library. You cannot index the id of the document object from Keystone as it carries a name of '_id' which is the same variable name elastic search uses to index your data entry. So I used a new id called 'prdID' to save the product id.